# Rails 5 assets not mentioned on the `applications.js` manifest are served?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, sprockets, rails-assets

Please enlighten me!

Let say I have the following assets structure in a Rails 5 application.

```
app/assets/javascripts
  application.js
  file1.js
```

In the `application.js` manifest I am not requiring `//= file1` neither I am using `require_tree .` directive.

If a JS file is not required in any way in the manifest `application.js` neither is it included in the `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w[]`

1. Is this asset going to be served?
2. If there is a tag in some view `<%= javascript_include_tag 'file1' %>` , should it work or raise an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that file is not served by default. By default (depending on Rails version/asset config), only the files listed in `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile`, by default application.js application.css or in newer Sprockets/Rails via files listed in `manifest.js` are available for direct serving via `javascript_include_tag`.

That 2. would raise an error.